# Would C# garbage collector free these objects?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

I am making a tree graph from nodes (I have a custom node class for them), and at certain points, I want to destroy the whole tree to start a new one. The nodes store pointers to their parents and children. I also have the root node stored explicitly in a variable. By my understanding, if I remove the reference to the root node, I cannot access any of the nodes anymore.

So, my question is, if I do remove the root node reference, will the garbage collector delete all the nodes? They do have pointers to each other, but I don't see any way in which I can access them anymore in this case.

Comment: Do you mean actuall **pointers** or **references**? They are related, but behave very differently.

Comment: My MyNode class, which the nodes are instantiated from, has these attributes: `public List<MyNode> childNodes; public MyNode parent;`

Comment: So each node has a **reference** to their parent. | Pointers are not managed by the runtime or relevant for the GC, references are. References use pointers somewhere down below, but they are not the same. So make sure you do not mix them up.

Comment: Alright, got it, thanks for the clarification! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: **Yes**

Any reference (and all of its descendants) that is unreachable from your current scope (and saved scopes in stack) will be collected

Answer (score 1):

> So, my question is, if I do remove the root node reference, will the garbage collector delete all the nodes? They do have pointers to each other, but I don't see any way in which I can access them anymore in this case.

Eventually: Yes.

The GC can collect everything without a "unbroken chain of strong references to a application root". If you dropped all strong references, they should no longer have that chain.

The questions is no longer *if* they will be collected, only *when*. The thing is, that a GC run is expensive so the runtime tries to run it as rarely as possible. If it only runs once during application closure, that is the ideal case. So do not be confussed by increasing memory useage.